# Why did Windows put my pagefile on a different drive, and can I move it back?

Tags: windows, virtual-memory, pagefile

I have a Windows 2012 server with a boot drive mounted as drive letter C, and a very large disk array (120 TB) attached and mounted as a single volume as drive letter F.

I happened to notice that recently Windows has put pagefile.sys on the F drive. You can see the settings here:

[image: Virtual memory settings screenshot, showing that there is one system managed paging file on the F drive.]

The C drive got a little low on space (although when I checked it had more than 10 GB of free space), but I've since cleared it out so it has 100 GB free. Perhaps that's why it was automatically moved off the C drive?

I don't particularly want it there, so **my question is this**: Is there any reason I should not force it to put the paging file back on the C drive? Is there an advantage to having it on the external disk array? It makes me nervous to mess with it, since I don't understand why it moved it in the first place, and I'm not super familiar with how the paging file works in general.

Thanks!

Comment: The reason it was put on another drive is due to the fact your system drive wasn't large enough to store it.  You will have to disable the page file then enable it so it can be recreated on the correct drive.

Comment: Ok, that's what I suspected, although I'm a little confused, because I don't think the free space went below 10 GB. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: You are allowing Windows to manage the size of the page file.  This means if at any time the page file required to be larger then that switch would have happened.